# Current Session id changes automaticaly causing loss of data

Tags: php, database, session, cookies

i m new to php i m using session_id() to insert item in my database cart table for the user who are not login and fetch these items on payment process using my session_id() but some times it returns different session id and left me loss of db records because i m not able to get records for this new session in db cart table.

Comment: Please provide us some code so we can help you debugging it.

Comment: (https://www.certsmarket.com/) try to select any item and use add to cart button

Comment: when you add to cart any item with out login that items is saved in cart db table against current session id but problem arises when some time when current session id changes automatically and we cannot find items saved against previous session id

Comment: got my my point ?

Comment: That is no code. I need PHP code to see what you are doing and what kind of data is being returned. Related to `session_id()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php. Robert explains it well!

Comment: function setCartValues($memid,$subscid,$prodid,$flag,$quantity,$status,$created_on,$sessid,$reorder,$extend,$serialcode,$did) {

   $query = "insert into cart (memberid, subscid, pid, flag, quantity, status, reorder, extend, serialcode, created_on, sessid, did) 

        values ($memid, $subscid, '$prodid', $flag, $quantity, $status, $reorder, $extend,$serialcode,'$created_on', '$sessid', $did)";
  $this->dbcon->insertRecord1($query);

 }

Comment: this is the function we use for inserting in cart table here $sessid=session_id()

Answer (score 0):

Because session id is regenerated **to prevent session fixation attacks**. You should not relay on it.

You can create some random id for example with uuid or str_shuffle/rand/ bin2hex(random_bytes(10)) etc. and store it in the session and for the payment get it from there.

Comment: can we prevent session regeneration ? @Robert

Comment: you can always impelement session handling on your own but I strongly advise you not to do it. http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php

Comment: what about this uniqid() function is it safe to use instead of session_id() @Robert

Comment: it's better to use it and save in session then using session_id(), it can be any other function that generates unique random id

Comment: i have made random id and save it in session varible name uid and insert it in db and using it for fetching cart records instead of session_id() it working well but i noticed after some time session variable show null and again i lost the cart data this same issue that i have with session_id()

Comment: please Robert reply

Comment: session has lifetime which is by default equal to 1440 s and can be changed in session.gc_maxlifetime